# Incorrect username appearing in Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, remote-desktop, macbook

The other night, I was looking around on my MacBook's files and I came across a program that was like screen sharing or remote control. I guess it came by default on the computer or something, because I didn't download that. I tried to connect to another computer on my internet and it didn't work. The computers name was "Blyth" and now in my terminal window it appears as:

`blyth~ harrisonbh:`

Im not sure why, and the `logout` command isn't working. My username is harrisonbh. Before the other night all was fine.

What should I do to log out of that? Also if you know about the screen sharing application and where I may be able to re-find it on the computer, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @ForeverWintr Yes

Comment: If you type `echo $PS1` in terminal, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

The username in your terminal is your laptop host-name. Here is a guide to help you change it to your liking! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7BhXkKbfe0